# Interchangeability of strike and establish

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

Can I use *strike* instead of *establish*? Like in this sentence:

> We don't know about the deals it may have **struck** with the other countries.

Comment: To "strike a deal" is an idiom, and its meaning is only tangential to that of the much larger and broader term *to establish*.

Comment: @Robusto you might want to write that as an answer

Comment: If you wish it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "strike a deal" is an idiom, and its meaning is only tangential to that of the much larger and broader term *to establish*.

Moreover, it's probably more common to talk about "making a deal" rather than "striking" one. And I have never actually heard anyone talk about "establishing" a deal; it would not be impossible to do that, but it would point in another direction, away from the common meaning you're looking for.

Comment: what about struck a deal vs made a deal?

Comment: In that context, "struck" would sound a little more dramatic than "make." That's about it. Use "strike" to emphasize some aspect regarding the process or the result.